# How to get the date and price with Python from this interactive graph?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, chart.js

I tried to extract the data from this graph (https://www.mtgprice.com/sets/Ravnica_Allegiance/Breeding_Pool) by trying web scraping with the Selenium library.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.mtgprice.com/sets/Ravnica_Allegiance/Breeding_Pool')
```

The only reference I found was in the Java Script code: (https://www.mtgprice.com/taneLayout/js/Charts.js)
(https://www.mtgprice.com/taneLayout/js/demos/charts/line.js).

> 

```
$(function () {

var d1 = [3.0, 3.0, 4.2, 4.4, 1.3, 2.9, 2.8, 1.9, 2.1, 3.4, 6.8, 8.1, 7.5, 7.1, 7.5, 9.5, 12.1, 12.4, 10.9, 10.4, 10.9, 9.1, 9.4, 10.5],
        d2 = [ 0.6, 1.2, 1.7, 0.7, 2.9, 4.1, 2.6, 3.7, 3.9, 1.7, 2.3, 3.0, 3.3, 4.8, 5.0, 4.8, 5.0, 3.2, 2.0, 2.4, 2.7, 3.5, 3.2, 2.8];         
            
var dt1 = [], 
        dt2 = [], 
        st = new Date(2012, 8, 6).getTime();

for( var i = 0; i < d2.length; i++ ) {
    dt1.push([st + i * 3600000, parseFloat( (d1[i]).toFixed( 3 ) )]);
    dt2.push([st + i * 3600000, parseFloat( (d2[i]).toFixed( 3 ) )]);
}

var data = [{ 
    data: dt1,
    label: 'Revenue'        
 }, { 
    data: dt2, 
    label: 'Expenses', 
    points: { show: false }, 
    lines: { lineWidth: 2, fill: false }        
 }];

Charts.line ( '#line-chart', data);
});
```

I want to get a table or dataframe with the date and price, from the different sellers that you can choose from on the right side of the screen.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the JS object containing all the datas from the chart in the Developer Console. Open the console and enter "results".

Use `driver.execute_script` to get that object.

```
driver.execute_script('return results')
```

The price is associated with a unix timestamp. To convert it to `datetime`:

```
import datetime

timestamp  = 1563092869548
timestamp = timestamp / 1000 # 2019-07-14 08:27:49.548000
date = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
```